# Do I have to use method for server-side only logic?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I would like to know if I have to use `Meteor.methods` if I am only doing server-side operations, and if not, where to put the logic.

I find myself doing this a lot:

```
Meteor.methods({
  someMethod: function () {
    if (! this.isSimulation) {
      // make third party api call, use node module, etc.
    }
  }
});
```

On the client side, I cannot make a third party API call to latency compensate, or use node module using `Npm.require` (assuming not using `meteorhacks:npm`). So I always wrap those methods around `if(! this.isSimulation)`.

But it seems unnecessary to put this logic in a method if I cannot use latency compensation. What is the widely adopted practice? Do I put those logic in a method still?

Answer (score 0):

You can just declare your pure server-side logic as server global functions living under the `server` directory.

`server/lib/logic.js`

```
serverLogic = function(){
  // your server-side only logic 
};
```

Then you can simply call your function anywhere in the server environment, inside a method, a collection hook, etc...

`server/anywhere.js`

```
serverLogic();
```